# How to write columns from multiple files into one data frame

Tags: r, lapply

I have around 100 text files each with 3 columns.  I want to read every file into an object and then the contents to a matrix that has 300 columns in it.

Created a matrix:

```
ptamat <- matrix(ncol=300, nrow=2665)
```

Read files into an object

```
myfiles <- lapply(Sys.glob('pta_out__*'), read.table)
```

Show contents of first 2 files in the myfiles object

```
myfiles[[1:2]]
```

Copy files in the 'myfiles' object to the matrix

```
ptamat[,1:300] <- myfiles[[1:100]]
```

The last part does not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should `cbind` all list elements:

```
do.call(cbind, myfiles)
```

Comment: The binding seems to work, but I still can't get the object to be written to ptamat.

Comment: You can just replace `ptamat` by assigning to it, there's no need to declare it beforehand.

Comment: If you're concerned about speed, you can replace your `read.table` with `scan` as in this link: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/06/06/29899.html

Comment: That works.  ptamat <- myfiles, then write.table(file='ptamat.txt', ptamat) did it.  Thanks.

Comment: I assume you did `myfiles <- do.call(cbind, myfiles)`.